# What's the purpose of the MOSFETS in this circuit

Tags: mosfet

[image: SEN0250]

I am trying to make sense of these schematics. UI is an LDO which provides 3V output.
Is it to isolate the BMI160 if there's not enough voltage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bidirectional logic level adapter. Check the note [AN10441 from NXP](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10441.pdf) to get the full description.

It also allow to isolate a powered down bus section. Some current can indeed be injected into the chip from the communication lines via it's ESD clamp diodes, this circuit protect the chip from this behavior.

I often use this circuit with a pair of 100 ohms resistors on the SDA/SCL lines with a dedicated ESD diode to get the signals out of the board.

[image: AN10441 - Level Shifter]